# Set up external storage to SD Card

Tags: external-sd

Just put 64gb Samsung SD Card into my galaxy j7 looking for advice on setup and moving pics and filed from internal.. possible to create widget or how to make a default to the external..help plz

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for a few minutes of your time Dan... I have a j7 its at compacity for its 16gb I put a Samsung SD Card in 64gb and I just need to put whatever I can that's ok for the phone to still function properly onto the SD.. My wife has about 4000 pics of my three daughters as they were growing up.. she wants to send them to me and i just need to be able to out them in the SD.... we are separated so it has to be by phone.. there is not a way to put the SD as default.. I have installed a few apps but dont want to start moving files not knowing.. I'm an idiot and just need my girls baby pictures..

Answer (score 0):

Settings- storage (name may be different) - default write disk. Select SD card.
Use app like files go to transfer photos to SD